# Invoices api response filtered by account codes provided

Tags: xero-api

I am trying to use the `https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices` api. I would like to receive the api response filter out by account Codes provided.
What I mean is I would like to receive only the invoices data pertaining to the account codes that I can pass as query parameter to api.

As per the api documentation, Xero doesn't support the filtering based on account codes.

**Use Case:** Building a customer integration (connector) for our customers between Xero and my company. Customer would only be willing to expose the invoice data that pertains to specific account codes (categories).

Please let me know if this is currently possible with current apis or if this can be added as an api enhancement by Xero in near future?

Comment: The account code for the invoice is potentially different for each line on the invoice, is that why Xero doesn't allow it as a search term? Or do you mean the contact code, but that is allowed and in fact is one of the examples.

Comment: Got it. Yes, I was referring to account code present in each line on the invoice and can potentially be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a great scenario to post a feature request on our community forums. If there is enough community support, our API team will try and get it on the roadmap: https://community.xero.com/business/topic/23/

The following are all the current (optional) parameters for **GET** **invoices**:

> https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/invoices#get

To solve your case for now, you will likely have to filter those invoices post API response after applying necessary filters/pagination due to the answer droopsnoot gave.

Comment: Got it, thanks @SerKnight for the reply. Putting in the request on Community Forum.